# xamarin monomac.appkit.nsapplicationdelegate is defined in assembly that is not referenced

Tags: xamarin, monomac, nsapplication

I'm trying to test some code from a tutorial on Xamarin, but I get this error:

```
The type 'MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplicationDelegate' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
```

But don't know where to look for the error.

I include a photo so you can see the error the same way I see it (hope it helps)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Within the Wave Engine tutorial projects the MSBuild build engine setting is turned on.

To use the normal build engine within the Options for the project (specifically 'Build' > 'General') there is an option to 'Use MSBuild build engine (recommended for this project type)' - just un-tick that option.